# Regex for alphanumeric caracters + Some special characters and space

Tags: regex, angular, validation

I'm trying to create a regex for space separated strings containing capital letters, numbers or the special characters `' / - ? : ( ) . , ''` (simple quote and double quote included).

I tried the following regex :

`^[A-Z0-9'/-?:().,\" ]*$`,

but it doesn't work when I type the `-` character.

Comment: Escape `-` or put at character class start/end.

Comment: Your regex is read as [/-?] (a range of characters).

Comment: I tried the following correction: ^[A-Z0-9'\/?:().,\"\- ]*$ but it doesn't work, I don't understand why